# Zooming in after setting coordinate system in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 and after setting up the coordinate system (WGS 1984) I added some georreferenced *.JPG files [image: Before zoom]

However when I try to zoom in/out to digitize, the zoom goes crazy: it doesn't display the image correctly and I'm not able to controll the zoom anymore, I just can visualize the overview by 'Zooming to Layer'. [image: Crazy zoom].

I tried to convert the image into a TIFF file but I'm getting the same bug.

Any hint on what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The georeferencing and/or defined coordinate system is wrong for the image. Look at the coordinate in the status bar at the lower right of the map. The units are decimal degrees, but the coordinates look like UTM or some other projected coordinate reference system.

Try redefining the coordinate system of the image first to whatever coordinate system the georeferencing is in.

Comment: I was checking with the recovered original data and I now have the image well georeferenced, however my previous edits are way too big to overlap correctly with the image in the WGS84 coordinate system. Is there any way to fix the shapefile size? I've already tried to redefine the projection but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please add the data extents to the question of any one you're having problems with, plus their current coordinate reference systems.